# Linux shell script run multiple shell scripts tabs

Tags: linux, shell, tabs, sh

I would like to make a .sh that runs multiple other ones .sh in new tabs/windows.

something like inside main.sh

```
"sh1.sh"

wait 5 seconds to load

"sh2.sh"

wait 5 seconds

"sh3.sh"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to run them in separate windows simultaneously, you need to background each process.

```
xterm -e sh1.sh &
sleep 5 # why do you want to pause between invocations?
xterm -e sh2.sh &
sleep 5
xterm -e sh3.sh &
```

This should probably be refactored to use a loop and/or a wrapper function.

```
for prog in sh1.sh sh2.sh sh3.sh; do
  xterm -e $prog &
  sleep 5
done
```

Comment: It Works! Thanks!
The sleep time is because the first script loads some heavy Java files, and the second script needs some services provided by the first one. And the same for sh 3 and 4.
Thanks again

Comment: In that case the second really should wait for the first, otherwise you will have timing problems (things will stop to work when the system is under heavy load, or something).  Also, if this fixed your problem, please mark this answer as accepted.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try xterm -e ~/sh1.sh as your command. It'll close as soon as the script has finished though.

Comment: It's not a problem if they close when they finish. But they are supposed to run simultaneously.
With xterm I only managed to execute sh1.sh and when I abort sh1.sh it executes sh2.sh
I would like to execute sh1 and sh2. Maybe I'm doing it wrong...

Comment: I just tried it again with the below code and it generated 3 separate windows:
main.sh:
xterm -e ~/test.sh
xterm -e ~/test.sh
xterm -e ~/test.sh

test.sh: 
echo "Hello"
sleep 10

Comment: Actually there should be & on the end of those xterms, I wasn't paying attention as I c+p'ed it.